# Is there a way in Reactor to ignore error signals?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have an array of multiple URLs and ports. For each of them, I need to send and receive something back:

```
Flux.fromArray(trackersArray)
    .flatMap(tracker -> 
               ConnectToTracker.connect(tracker.getTracker(), tracker.getPort()))
```

*I communicate with the servers in `UDP` so I can't tell if a server is alive or not unless I send a message which 'by some set of rules, need to respond to it.*

`ConnectToTracker.connect` may send a `onNext` signal if the server response or `onError` signal if, for example, the server doesn't response (`SocketTimeOutException`) or any other failure (general `IOException`).

I don't want to terminate the `flux` if, for example, the `onError` signal is equal to `SocketTimeOutException`. **Instead, I would like to try communicating with every tracker I got.**

[This link](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which.errors) contains all the operations I can use to handle errors **but not ignore them.**

I'm using `Reactor 3` if this matters.

**Update:**

I made an *ugly* trick, but works:

```
Flux.fromArray(trackersArray)
        .handle((Tracker tracker, SynchronousSink<ConnectResponse> sink) -> {
            ConnectToTracker.connect(tracker.getTracker(), tracker.getPort())
                    .subscribe(sink::next, error -> {
                        if (!(error instanceof SocketTimeoutException))
                            sink.error(error);
                    }, sink::complete);
        })
```

Please fill free to answer if you have anything better.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

since you are already processing urls in a flatmap, use `onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty())`. this will let flatmap ignore the error.
edit: within the flatmap, on the right hand side of the lambda

Comment: if the source has been fully processed, then it will complete, that's the whole spirit of Flux. if element 4 out of 6 errors, the solution above WITHIN THE FLATMAP will skip that element and proceed with element 5

Comment: Hi I run into the problem when use onErrorResume(). The error arises:
org.springframework.transaction.reactive.TransactionContextManager$NoTransactionInContextException
Do you know how to fix it?

I faced that error with KafkaReactiveTemplateConsumer

Answer (score 8):

Now we have `reactor.core.publisher.onErrorContinue()` in version `3.3.2`, which allows you to send `onNext()` signal when some elements is `onError()`. Use `log()` you will see better.

The signature is `(throwable, instance)` so if you want to log the errored out one, is useful.

```java
Flux.fromIterable(aList)
    .flatMap(this::xxxx)
    .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> {
        log.error("Error while processing {}. Cause: {}", o, throwable.getMessage());
})
    ....
```

Comment: Any idea how to test this using StepVerifier? Even in this version, you can only expect an error as a last step, there's no "assertError" similar to assertNext. Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is checking the logs in console.. because in this operator you can do nothing about this error but log it. Maybe you can wrap it with another exception as per doc, but then the operator loses its sense(you want to know what happened without stopping, but wrapping it will propagate and stop the pipeline). Haven't tried, not sure.

Comment: @Konrad, what the flux does is ignore exceptions. So if you need to test the flux throw an exception inside `this.xxx()` and check whether `StepVerifier` completes successfully.

Answer (score 5):

```
Flux.fromArray(trackersArray)
.flatMap(tracker -> 
           ConnectToTracker.connect(tracker.getTracker(), tracker.getPort())
                .onErrorResume(SocketTimeoutException.class, __ -> Mono.empty()))
```

Maybe this is better of doing the same it will on recover from SocketTimeOut and if the exception is other i will go for the onError